# Whether one could use the verb drink with ice-cold tea?

Tags: word-usage

I have the idea that we need to say "I *took* (not *drank*) my tea (or coffee) . . ." because we consume these beverages hot.

If my idea is true, should we use *take* even when referring to *cold* tea or coffee?

Comment: You can (in the US) say "drink" for any beverage, hot or cold.  Saying "take" would be viewed as a bit of an affectation, except when being asked, eg, "How do you take your coffee?"  (Ie, do you want cream and sugar?)

Comment: Here on SEA, it seems quite common to 'take' food, and conversely 'eat' medicine.

Comment: At least in American, one drinks beverages - hot or cold is immaterial - eats foods, and but takes solid or liquid medicines.

Comment: Eating implies chewing.  I suppose one could eat flintstones chewable vitamins.  Don't recommend doing that with aspirin.

Comment: @RoaringFish I disagree. I don't think all countries in SEA are the same in this respect. For example, in my first language (Thai), we can กิน ("eat"), ทาน (sort of a hybrid of "eat" + "give"), รับประทาน (sort of "receive"), but don't "take". We can either กิน ("eat") or ดื่ม ("drink") any kind of liquid, though in a more formal occasion, ดื่ม ("drink") is preferred. (No "have" equivalent.) And one can use รับ (sort of "receive" or "take") when one wants to offer food or beverage to another person. And it's best for learners, IMHO, to think that any of those is not related to English at all.

Comment: @DamkerngT. ~ I was refering to people using English as their second language. In Singapore for sure (I lived there for ten years) it is standard to take noodles and eat an aspirin. I have also encountered the same usage in Indonesia (where I live now), in Vietnam, in China, in Cambodia, in Brunei, and in Thailand. I initially thought it was a 'Singlish' thing, possibly from the whole TCM thing blurring the boundaries between food and medicine, but subsequent travel revealed it to be quite widespread.

Comment: @RoaringFish If it's that widespread, I don't know about it. (It didn't occur to me when I was in Singapore, but it was only a week or two in total, so it's probably too short for me.) If it's commonly used in all those countries, I guess that it must be some kind of common (mis)teaching, rather than the first language interference. Thanks for the (curious!) info. I'll look into this issue when I can (probably not very soon, though :-).

Comment: @Roa *To eat medicine* is a direct/literal translation from Mandarin.

Answer (score 3):

***Any* liquid** can use "drink". Even dangerous things. Temperature does not matter.

> Coke, tea, water, bleach, milk, juice, ...

"take" is either used literally, or to refer to the consumption of **medicine**.

> Take some Tylenol. I hope it will make you feel better.

**Food** often uses "eat".

> I ate sausages, he eats corn, Manny is eating yogurt, Jacqueline had eaten a large turkey, ...

**Any food/drinks** also often use "have" to refer to their consumption:

> had breakfast, had a glass of water, had some tea, will have ice cream, have steak for dinner, had some cereal, will have a coke, have hot chocolate, ...

Comment: I believe "take" is also used when you buy something (e.g. "I took a cup of coffee at the gas station")

Comment: Odd, I haven't encountered that. I thought "buy" was used in those cases. (Canadian here.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I heard it somewhere. And the dictionary I use ( https://slovari.yandex.ru/take/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4 , it's English-Russian but there are examples) shows that "take" can mean "buy" and "choose"

Comment: American here, I've heard take before, but buy is more common.

Comment: *I take my tea with milk and sugar.*